# Como redirecionar url - redirect 301 - através de uma requisição ? (HttpURLConnection)

Tags: java, spring, http, redirecionamento-de-url

Estou tentando obter um status code[ redirect 301, Location : ] através de uma requisição.
Esta requisição traz como parâmetro um id associado a uma url armazenada em banco (nesse caso, um Map), com o id, busco a url e com o a classe HttpURLConnection instancio uma conexão. Esse  é o problema: uma nova conexão e não um redirect. Tanto que o status que recebo é um status code 200.

p.s essa é minha primeira pergunta por aqui e não sou nada experiente, então foi mal se ela não tá bem formulada.

o método que descrevi é esse :

```java
@GetMapping("/geturl/{id}")
    public String getUrl(@PathVariable("id") String id) throws IOException {

        String url = "";
        System.out.println("We are in GET url");
        System.out.println("Id value " + id);

        if (urlRepository.findById(id) != null) {

            try {

                url = urlRepository.findById(id).getUrl();
                System.out.println("This is the  URL ... " + url);


                URL obj = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
                conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
                conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
                conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");
                conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                conn.connect();



                System.out.println("Request URL ... " + url);

                boolean redirect = false;

                // normally, 3xx is redirect
                int status = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                            || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                            || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
                        redirect = true;
                }

                System.out.println("Response Code ... " + status);
                System.out.println("Location  : " + conn.getHeaderField("Location"));

                if (redirect) {

                    // get redirect url from "location" header field
                    String newUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");

                    // get the cookie if need, for login
                    String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

                    // open the new connnection again
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
                    conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
                    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
                    conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");

                    System.out.println("Redirect to URL : " + newUrl);

                }

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    html.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();

                System.out.println("URL Content... \n" + html.toString());
                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return url;
        }

        return "404 Not Found";
    }
```

Boa parte do código veio daqui : https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/

qualquer omissão só sinalizar.

as saídas dos system outs :

```
We are in GET url

Id value 08316aaa

This is the  URL ... http://www.google.com

Request URL ... http://www.google.com

Response Code ... 200

Location  : null

URL Content... 

<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="pt-BR"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script nonce="nN9LKT6NkpSrzvOI7rKOPA==">(function(){window.google={kEI:'6mNxXf7BC7rM5OUPmbaggAE',kEXPI:'0,1353746,2016,1641,781,1225,731,223,510,1065,3152,57,320,207,1017,54,1430,526,51,2,124,10,169,544,226,112,160,240,138,1132071,1197736,329531,1294,12383,4855,32692,15247,867,12163,7235,9286,363,3320,5505,2442,5942,1119,2,579,727,2431,1362,283,4040,4968,773,2249,4745,3118,6196,669,1050,1496,312,1478,7,2,489,2044,8909,5297,2016,38,918,875,1217,1364,350,1,1260,2736,3061,2,631,3240,4192,3874,2884,20,317,1118,482,420,2128,1,369,2777,520,399,992,509,776,8,109,2687,219,670,78,48,553,11,15,1278,2212,202,323,5,68,1177,7,83,244,513,324,193,1470,52,820,2620,335,449,34,108,152,52,1137,2,1509,554,606,1317,522,186,593,1182,520,361,1586,747,61,158,26,72,112,44,1102,328,1284,17,83,336,81,507,1919,1639,607,101,373,1339,729,501,557,1601,1492,134,521,252,181,79,1288,28,496,7,504,224,592,523,695,152,3,201,1227,321,52,736,369,269,221,980,2,378,284,243,310,116,958,349,677,220,77,1069,289,193,6,6,275,299,109,467,12,23,122,135,9,397,44,8,112,2,91,75,528,129,119,20,35,55,3,468,56,16,838,127,676,29,292,219,9,68,3,3,249,565,441,524,203,96,2,241,8,5896398,6000372,94,2799874,4,1572,549,333,444,1,2,80,1,900,583,9,304,1,8,1,2,2132,1,1,1,1,1,414,1,748,141,59,726,3,7,563,1,3559,2,115,27,11',authuser:0,kscs:'c9c918f0_6mNxXf7BC7rM5OUPmbaggAE',kGL:'BR',kBL:'nfid'};google.sn='webhp';google.kHL='pt-BR';google.jsfs='Ffpdje';})();(function(){google.lc=[];google.li=0;google.getEI=function(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||google.kEI};google.getLEI=function(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b};google.https=function(){return"https:"==window.location.protocol};google.ml=function(){return null};google.time=function(){return(new Date).getTime()};google.log=function(a,b,e,c,g){if(a=google.logUrl(a,b,e,c,g)){b=new Image;var d=google.lc,f=google.li;d[f]=b;b.onerror=b.onload=b.onabort=function(){delete d[f]};google.vel&&google.vel.lu&&google.vel.lu(a);b.src=a;google.li=f+1}};google.logUrl=function(a,b,e,c,g){var d="",f=google.ls||"";e||-1!=b.search("&ei=")||(d="&ei="+google.getEI(c),-1==b.search("&lei=")&&(c=google.getLEI(c))&&(d+="&lei="+c));c="";!e&&google.cshid&&-1==b.search("&cshid=")&&"slh"!=a&&(c="&cshid="+google.cshid);a=e||"/"+(g||"gen_204")+"?atyp=i&ct="+a+"&cad="+b+d+f+"&zx="+google.time()+c;/^http:/i.test(a)&&google.https()&&(google.ml(Error("a"),!1,{src:a,glmm:1}),a="");return a};}).call(this);(function(){google.y={};google.x=function(a,b){if(a)var c=a.id;else{do c=Math.random();while(google.y[c])}google.y[c]=[a,b];return!1};google.lm=[];google.plm=function(a){google.lm.push.apply(google.lm,a)};google.lq=[];google.load=function(a,b,c){google.lq.push([[a],b,c])};google.loadAll=function(a,b){google.lq.push([a,b])};}).call(this);google.f={};var a=window.location,b=a.href.indexOf("#");if(0<=b){var c=a.href.substring(b+1);/(^|&)q=/.test(c)&&-1==c.indexOf("#")&&a.replace("/search?"+c.replace(/(^|&)fp=[^&]*/g,"")+"&cad=h")};</script><style>#gb{font:13px/27px Arial,sans-serif;height:30px}#gbz,#gbg{position:absolute;white-space:nowrap;top:0;height:30px;z-index:1000}#gbz{left:0;padding-

....
```

Done

Obrigadao.

Answer (score -1):

Cada site faz o tratamento do request da sua forma.

Quando você faz um request para o http://www.google.com, uns engenheiros pensaram:

- Pô, legal, eu **tenho** o que você quer.
   Toma aqui o seu response com o conteúdo e o status code **200** que tudo deu certo. Tchau, hein!

Quando você faz o request para o http://www.twitter.com, outros engenheiros pensaram:

- Cara, eu **não sei** tratar essa sua requisição.
   Vou colocar no seu response o status code **301** e uma **URL** onde você vai **buscar** o conteúdo, belê? Tchau.

Troque a sua *implementação* para algum site que tenha este comportamento e receberá o status code 301, como o do [Twitter](http://www.twitter.com):

```java
 url = urlRepository.findById(id).getUrl();
```